# Sort the color by row and arrange it alphabetically. Python

Tags: python

`\I need to set the color of each row to light gray and dark gray based on what is in the column"Status Blokace"

And sort the same column alphabetically.

I'm learning to program, and I know that this code is not written very well, but I'm struggling with this.`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd

def update_data():
global data
data = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\ondresab\\Documents\\Data.xlsx")
data = data\[(data\['Status Blokace'\] == "K odblokovani") | (data\['Status Blokace'\] == "K     zablokovani")\]
display_data()

def save_to_excel():
data.to_excel("C:\\Users\\ondresab\\Documents\\Data.xlsx", index=False)

def change_status(index):
if data.at\[index, 'Status Blokace'\] == "K odblokovani":
data.at\[index, 'Status Blokace'\] = "Odblokovany"
elif data.at\[index, 'Status Blokace'\] == "K zablokovani":
data.at\[index, 'Status Blokace'\] = "Zablokovany"
save_to_excel()  # Save the modified data to Excel
display_data()

def display_data():
for widget in form.winfo_children():
widget.destroy()

for index, row in data.iterrows():
ttk.Label(form, text=row\['Employee ID'\]).grid(row=index, column=0)
ttk.Label(form, text=row\['Login'\]).grid(row=index, column=1)
ttk.Label(form, text=row\['Meno'\]).grid(row=index, column=2)
ttk.Label(form, text=row\['Datum zmeny statusu'\]).grid(row=index, column=3)
ttk.Label(form, text=row\['Status Blokace'\]).grid(row=index, column=4)
ttk.Label(form, text=row\['Duvod Blokace'\]).grid(row=index, column=5)
ttk.Button(form, text="Done", command=lambda i=index: change_status(i)).grid(row=index,     column=6)

root = tk.Tk()root.title("Data Form")root.geometry("800x800")

data = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\ondresab\\Documents\\Data.xlsx")data = data\[(data\['Status         Blokace'\] == "K odblokovani") | (data\['Status Blokace'\] == "K zablokovani")\]

refresh_button = tk.Button(root, text="Refresh", command=update_data)refresh_button.pack()

columns = \["Employee ID", "Login", "Meno", "Datum zmeny statusu", "Status Blokace", "Duvod     Blokace", "Action"\]form = ttk.Frame(root)form.pack()

display_data()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Besides your indentation being broken in your posted code, what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

I am also relatively new in helping others solve their problems but I think this simplified-ish code should give you what you're looking for, lemme know if it works for you.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd

def update_data():
    global data
    data = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\ondresab\\Documents\\Data.xlsx")
    data = data[(data['Status Blokace'] == "K odblokovani") | (data['Status Blokace'] == "K zablokovani")]
    display_data()

def save_to_excel():
    data.to_excel("C:\\Users\\ondresab\\Documents\\Data.xlsx", index=False)

def change_status(index):
    if data.at[index, 'Status Blokace'] == "K odblokovani":
        data.at[index, 'Status Blokace'] = "Odblokovany"
    elif data.at[index, 'Status Blokace'] == "K zablokovani":
        data.at[index, 'Status Blokace'] = "Zablokovany"
    save_to_excel()  # Save the modified data to Excel
    display_data()

def display_data():
    for widget in form.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    data.sort_values(by='Status Blokace', inplace=True)  # Sort data by 'Status Blokace'

    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        # Set row color based on 'Status Blokace'
        row_color = 'lightgray' if row['Status Blokace'] == 'Odblokovany' else 'darkgray'

        for col_index, column in enumerate(columns):
            ttk.Label(form, text=row[column], background=row_color).grid(row=index, column=col_index)

        ttk.Button(form, text="Done", command=lambda i=index: change_status(i)).grid(row=index, column=len(columns))

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Data Form")
root.geometry("800x800")

data = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\ondresab\\Documents\\Data.xlsx")
data = data[(data['Status Blokace'] == "K odblokovani") | (data['Status Blokace'] == "K zablokovani")]

refresh_button = tk.Button(root, text="Refresh", command=update_data)
refresh_button.pack()

columns = ["Employee ID", "Login", "Meno", "Datum zmeny statusu", "Status Blokace", "Duvod Blokace", "Action"]
form = ttk.Frame(root)
form.pack()

display_data()

root.mainloop()
```